# C++ Libcurl + Cloudflare

Tags: c, libcurl, cloudflare

I am having some troubles when I want to make a get request with my C++ application using LibCurl and on my website to test I am using Cloudflare Under Attack mode, from what I tried the problem is under attack mode but I want to make it compatible cause its more secure and filter some unwanted people etc on your domain, so how I can make my request successfully with this mode enabled?

I am doing the request like this:

```
            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_URL, "https://website.com");
            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &Buffer);
            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1L);
            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
            curl_easy_setopt(CurlContex, CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
```

-EDIT

Bad explained my problem is the request got failed and doesn't complete cause the under attack mode

**Already solved by CloudFlare Headers thanks.**

Thank you for your help, greetings.

Comment: "I am having troubles" does not describe a problem. What do you want to happen? What happens instead? Be specific when explaining the problem, and quote any errors in full.

Comment: Have you tried creating an "Allow" firewall rule for your ip or for a header that only you will send to the server? Turning on "Under Attack" mode will send a JS challenge that will be easy for browsers but nearly impossible for you to solve with Curl.

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry for bad explaining i ve edited it. The problem is when i have enabled the Under Attack mode the request doens't complete for example if i try to download something it simple doens't do.

Comment: @drussey I din't tried it, i will try with the header cause its the most rebiable way for me.

Comment: @drussey Solved by your reply thank you, is there anyway to give you the solution to this answer or something?

Comment: Since you've solved your problem - please either write an answer to your question, or delete the question altogether.

Comment: @einpoklum I ve do it thanks.